# Fit a title on multiple lines in a header (Friggeri CV)

Tags: tikz-pgf, friggeri-cv

I'm helping a friend with LaTeX to make her a CV that looks very nice using the Friggeri CV template. I'm experienced with it but not with Tikz, which is used to make the black header at the beginning with the name, and a short personal statement.

I would like to write this statement over two lines. I used "multilines" to do so, but 
1) the second line seems to be not centered
2) I can't manage to fit everything in the header, and I don't want to increase its height.

The solution would be to move the name above, and reduce the margins. Does someone know how to do this? Attached is a MWE as well as the CLS class file here : https://github.com/oroce/cv/blob/master/friggeri-cv.cls

Thank you very much.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\newcommand{\manylines}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1.05cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\renewenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor}         ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{4}(0.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

\begin{document}
\header{John}{Doe}
       {\manylines{Intergalactic master of the world looking the best job ever\\with blablablabla  bladibloudiblabla}}

\begin{aside}
  \section{About}
    Blabla Road
     Nº1 Meow 
    Wof
    {111 111 111}
  \section{Languages}
    English
\end{aside}

\section{Educación}
\begin{entrylist}
  \vspace{1mm}
  \entry
    {\manylines{Sep. 2015\\May 2016}}
    {Estudiante de Comunicación Audiovisual en programa de intercambio}
    {\\Universidad de California en Santa Bárbara, Estados Unidos}
    {}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By `multilines` do you mean the command you defined called `manylines`, which is defined as a flushleft single-column tabular? How should that be centred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the *original* CV. And license also still there. Very good.

Since you don't want to change the height of that box, you have to either make the fontsize smaller, or just reduce the line spacing a bit.

I decided to do the last one. Add the following into your preamble.

```
\newcommand{\manylines}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}% this is now centered
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\header}{24pt}{16pt}{}{}
```